# Normal constant definition versus lambda constant definition

Tags: lambda, isabelle, theorem-proving

I have these two definitions. Why are they unfolding differently? How can I prove the "oops"-ed lemmas? (And in general, what is the difference between these two definitions in Isabelle, internally?)

(Please don't direct me to external links because I usually get swamped by the information there.)

```
  definition "f x y = x+y"
  definition "g ≡ λx y. x+y"

  value "f 1 2" (* "1 + (1 + 1)" :: "'a" *)
  value "g 1 2" (* "1 + (1 + 1)" :: "'a" *)

  value "f 1"   (* "op + 1" :: "'a ⇒ 'a" *)
  value "g 1"   (* "op + 1" :: "'a ⇒ 'a" *)

  value "f"     (* "op +" :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a" *)
  value "g"     (* "op +" :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ 'a" *)


  lemma "f x y≡g x y" 
    apply (simp add:f_def g_def)
  done 

  lemma "f x ≡g x"
    apply (simp add:f_def g_def)
    (* f x ≡ op + x *)
  oops

  lemma "f ≡ g"
    apply (simp add:f_def g_def)
    (* f ≡ op + *)
  oops
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between a definition with explicit arguments on the left (like `f x y = x + y`) and one with lambdas on the right (like `g = (%x y. x + y)`) is what kind of defining equation you get out of it.

For the former it is

```
f_def: "f ?x ?y = ?x + ?y"
```

(i.e., this equation is *only* applicable if all arguments of `f` are present, thus it is neither applicable to `f` alone nor to the partially applied `f x`, for example) and for the latter

```
g_def: "g = op +"
```

(where `op +` is just syntactic sugar for `%x y. x + y`; note that this equation, in contrast to the former, is applicable to *every* occurrence of `g` whatsoever).

There are two common techniques that can be used to handle partially applied functions vs. functions with explicit argument list.

1. The attribute `[abs_def]` transforms an equation with arguments into one with lambdas. E.g., `f_def [abs_def]` results in `f = op +`.
2. The lemma `ext` (for *extensionality*) explicitly adds arguments to equations between functions.

   ```
   ext: "(!!x. ?f x = ?g x) ⟹ ?f = ?g"
   ```

For your lemmas either of this techniques suffices. Either add `[abs_def]` to every occurrence of `f_def` in your proof attempts or do the following.

```
lemma "f x = g x"
apply (intro ext)
apply (simp add: f_def g_def)
done

lemma "f = g"
apply (intro ext)
apply (simp add: f_def g_def)
done
```

Where `intro` applies `ext` as often as possible (as determined by the type of a function).

**Note** that I used HOL equality (`op =`) rather than Pure equality (`op ≡`) in the above proofs. While both are logically equivalent, the lemma `ext` only applies to the former. As a general rule: for Isabelle/HOL stick to `op =` whenever possible.

Comment: There is also the simplification theorem `fun_eq_iff` which can come in handy.